# What's the meaning of "No law less than ourselves owning" in this Whitman's poem?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I come across a poem of Whitman named "WE TWO BOYS TOGETHER CLINGING
", finding it hard to understand the expression "No law less than ourselves owning". The whole thing is as follows:

> We two boys together clinging,
>   One the other never leaving,
>   Up and down the roads going, North and South.
>   excursions making,
>   Power enjoying, elbows stretching, fingers clutching,
>   Arm'd and fearless, eating, drinking, sleeping, loving,
>   **No law less than ourselves owning**, sailing, soldiering,
>   thieving, threatening,
>   Misers, menials, priests alarming, air breathing, water
>   drinking, on the turf or the sea-beach dancing,
>   Cities wrenching, ease scorning, statutes mocking,
>   feebleness chasing,
>   Fulfilling our foray.

Both the syntax and the word "own" perplex me. Any hint? (Comments and interpretations about the poem itself are welcome, too!)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please detail the research you've already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.).

Comment: "own" means "obey"

Comment: @Fattie -- does it? I am familiar with the sense 'acknowledge', which is what Whitman means: and if you acknowledge a law you recognise that it should be obeyed, but you could choose to break it! Do you have a source that gives "obey" as a meaning of "own"?

Comment: "acknowledge" and "obey" mean the same thing - sure, there are endless **shades of meaning** in English, you're right.

Answer (score 21):

Own is being used in the archaic sense here, see:

[Own](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/own)

> archaic with object Acknowledge paternity, authorship, or possession
>   of. ‘he has published little, trivial things which he will not own’ -
>   OLD.

The fact that they will not own any law other than themselves means that they will submit to no law less than themselves.

Taking your original phrase:

> No law less than ourselves owning

You could rephrase less poetically to mean:

> Answering to no one else but ourselves.

Comment: Yes, or possibly use a synonym and otherwise keep the original form: "No law less than ourselves granting", or "No law less than ourselves conceding".

Comment: I like 'Answering to no one else but ourselves.' but the original sounds much more arrogant. I wonder if it did at the time.

Comment: This sense of "own" persists in modern usage in phrasal verb "to own up to" (something).

Comment: Why make it complicated?  "own" means "obey".  Couldn't be simpler.

Comment: Wouldn't it be "Answering *at least* to ourselves"?

Comment: I think there is also an implication that the boys childishly see *all* man's laws as "less than ourselves." That is, the surface reading is "We acknowledge no law which is inferior to ourselves" but the subtext (IMHO) is "We acknowledge no laws, and justify it by regarding all laws as inferior to ourselves."

Comment: Another way to "translate" it in to modern language would be "take onboard".  (Inasmuch as, nobody today under about 40 is literate enough to know that phrase - so I guess that would be translating it into "mid 20th century language".)

Answer (score 20):

The poem uses complement fronting. What this means is that the complements of the verbs, which would normally appear after them, have been moved to a preverbal position. (The last line reverts to a normal phrase order to bring the poem to a close.)

So, instead of *clinging together* or *never leaving the other* or *alarming misers, menials, priests* we see:

- together clinging
- the other never leaving
- misers, menials, priests alarming.

The Original Poster's example, *No law less than ourselves owning*, if rendered with a normal phrase order, would read:

> Owning no law less than ourselves, ...

There is an archaic use of *own*, as mentioned by @Gary meaning *to recognise*. Here are some examples:

- to own your mistakes
- [The Scottish lords were not to serve beyond the sea against their will, and were pardoned for their recent violence, in return owning allegiance to Edward.](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/owning)
- [... when each chief was a monarch owning no law but his own will, no master but the King of Heaven.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lsEkAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA237&lpg=PA237&dq=...+when+each+chief+was+a+monarch+owning+no+law+but+his+own+will,+no+master+but+the+King+of+Heaven.&source=bl&ots=dHZLVQALvi&sig=LKCIg7DhoeLsYANMfU-m6U5rORs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYmp3c-rvXAhXM2qQKHc4oD84Q6AEIKDAB#v=onepage&q=...%20when%20each%20chief%20was%20a%20monarch%20owning%20no%20law%20but%20his%20own%20will%2C%20no%20master%20but%20the%20King%20of%20Heaven.&f=false)
- [a man who reproaches himself for lack of gall, and pours out the most biting irony upon an egotistical court-circle seeking only its own advantage, and owning no law but external decorum](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RGLhuHLF7QMC&pg=PA334&lpg=PA334&dq=himself+for+lack+of+gall,+and+pours+out+the+most+biting+irony+upon+an+egotistical+court-circle+seeking+only+its+own+advantage,+and+owning+no+law+but+external+decorum&source=bl&ots=vr6TmpdZ0H&sig=Hdpr-srZRVruXGrJBm9gXnJY0jU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja_s-R-rvXAhUJoqQKHbZADRQQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=himself%20for%20lack%20of%20gall%2C%20and%20pours%20out%20the%20most%20biting%20irony%20upon%20an%20egotistical%20court-circle%20seeking%20only%20its%20own%20advantage%2C%20and%20owning%20no%20law%20but%20external%20decorum&f=false)

The word *less* is sometimes used with a meaning similar to *other*, especially if there is some kind of negation involved. Here's a definition from [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/less)

> 3. in any way different; other:
>
> > He is nothing less than a thief.

Consider:

- It was none less than Bob himself.
- It was none other than Bob himself.

The Original Poster's example can therefore be understood as meaning:

> Recognising no other law than ourselves.

Here, of course, *law* refers not to a single rule, but to a ruling authority.

Answer (score 0):

To take no notice of or to heed no other than each other. I doubt Whitman meant the word "law" to be understood in its literal sense.